# Can't run ipv6 tunnel - add tunnel "sit0" failed: No buffer space available

Tags: networking, server, interface, ipv6, tunnel

I stack with the error "add tunnel "sit0" failed: No buffer space available".

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
    auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet6 auto

auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
        address 2001:470:1f2e:21c::2
        netmask 64
        endpoint 216.218.200.58
        local 89.223.25.23
        ttl 255
        gateway 2001:470:1f2e:21c::1
        
        up ip addr add 2001:470:e206:cdc7:5f42:0c51:ce33:50d3/48 dev he-ipv6
        up ip addr add 2001:470:e206:45f9:351f:93f0:6e09:2372/48 dev he-ipv6
        up ip addr add 2001:470:e206:07f2:8d22:2e0d:b4f0:d175/48 dev he-ipv6
```

**ifconfig -a**

```
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:01:23:11
          inet addr:89.223.25.23  Bcast:89.223.31.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe01:2311/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a04:ac00:4:294b:5054:ff:fe01:2311/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:109028 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:103771 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:20559792 (20.5 MB)  TX bytes:160641037 (160.6 MB)

he-ipv6   Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          inet6 addr: 2001:470:1f2e:21c::2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::59df:1917/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:109864 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:109864 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:81562375 (81.5 MB)  TX bytes:81562375 (81.5 MB)

sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**Result: service networking restart**

```
   ● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-01-28 03:42:01 MSK; 35s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 8074 ExecStop=/sbin/ifdown -a --read-environment --exclude=lo (code=exited, status=0/comCCESS)
  Process: 15140 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 15134 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=0/S
 Main PID: 15140 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 28 03:42:01 corp.com systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
Jan 28 03:42:01 corp.com ifup[15140]: add tunnel "sit0" failed: No buffer space available
Jan 28 03:42:01 corp.com ifup[15140]: Failed to bring up he-ipv6.
Jan 28 03:42:01 corp.com systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 28 03:42:01 corp.com systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
Jan 28 03:42:01 corp.com systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 28 03:42:01 corp.com systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with recomlt 'exit-code'.
```

Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. My server has enough ssd space and memory. Same config successfully work on another server Ubuntu 16. Please help.

Comment: 16.04.6 is the current point release, if possible updating your server may reduce the troubles you are experiencing. Be aware that 16.04 will be [EOL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL) in 2021-04.